# JAGS model to PyMC

Tags: bayesian, python, jags, pymc

I'm trying to translate a code that I have written in JAGS to PyMC but I'm getting stuck due to the recursion in the JAGS code that I can't figure out how to pass it to PyMC.

The model in JAGS is defined as:

```
model {
  # Priors
  a ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001);
  b ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001);
  tau ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.0001);
  X0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  x[1] ~ dnorm(a + b * X0, tau)
  
  # Likelihood
  for(i in 2:N) { 
    v[i] <- a + b * x[i-1]
    x[i] ~ dnorm(v[i], tau)
  }
}
```

and in PyMC I have:

```
from pymc import Gamma, Model, Normal, sample

with Model() as one_factor:
    tau = Gamma("tau", alpha=10**-1, beta=10**-4)
    a = Normal("a", 0, sigma=10**-4)
    b = Normal("b", 0, sigma=10**-4)
    
    x0 = Normal(0, 10**-3)
```

which is missing the `x[1]` part and the for, but I couldn't fine anywhere an example of how to do it.